# menu of maven JRE runner does not seem to have any impact in IntellijIDEA IDE

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, menu, version

i am new to IntellijIDEA and actually make some tests to understand
the different behaviours of the build/run regarding different options in IDE.

To make my test, i compiled in java 15 bytecode, with a jdk 17.
Then, i want to run.

i have two jdk installed on my machine : jdk11 & jdk17.
i noticed that my application can run only if i configure project like that

```
File/Project structure/Project/SDK --> JDK17
```

Ok, i am comfortable with that, so my question is :
what is the use of the menu :

```
File/settings/build tools/maven/runner/JRE ????
```

In fact, whatever the version of jdk provided in this menu, it has no impact for the run.
So, what is the purpose of this

```
build tools/maven/runner
```

menu ?

thanks.

Comment: It's the JDK version used in Maven projects to run the Maven process that imports the project from pom.xml. It's the same as changing JAVA_HOME in your terminal and then run Maven. This JDK should be normally the same as your project JDK. You can delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven (https://i.imgur.com/97RdrDb.png). In this case, Maven Runner JRE will be used.

Comment: @CrazyCoder i tried to delegate IDE actions to Maven, and setting a jdk17, while i stayed on jdk11 in menu project structure, just for testing. it does not work. it seems the more recent jdk must absolutly set in project structure menu.

Comment: Sorry, can't confirm. Works fine for me: https://i.imgur.com/FkOjTIx.png. JDK 19 set for Maven is used when delegating instead of the project JDK 17. This JDK will be also used by default if you start a Maven goal from the Maven tool window in IntelliJ IDEA. Does it answer your question?

Comment: @CrazyCoder in fact JDK is the one used in the Maven tool window. But, for the rest, it is not clear, as there is a third place to configure jdk : profile menu with "Build and Run". i will create a new post for that.